# How can i change the content of a different page, when my current page is closed?

Tags: javascript, html

On my html page i have a function that is called when the page is closed.
I want this function to change some elements from a different page. Is that possible?

Comment: It depends. If you post some example html along with an attempt at the javascript, then we may be able to help you with a specific answer. Generally speaking, what you are trying to do is probably better handled server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a handle to that window because you created it, you'd have to save the information about the modification away somewhere. You could do this by storing the information on the server side. It could also be done purely client side using cookies or local storage.

A very simplistic cookie-based example:

page-to-close.html:

```
<body onunload="javascript:document.cookie='modified by other page'">
```

page-to-modify.html:

```
<script>                                                                        
  var message = document.cookie ? document.cookie : 'first visit'               
  document.write(message)                                                       
</script>
```